# AJAX sends empty array to PHP

Tags: php, ajax

I have the following ajax function called from `input text` filed `onchange` event:

```
    $.ajax({
    url:'../controllers/aj_del_edit_word.php',
    tyep:"Post",
    data:{act :'dele', newWord : q, wordtype : w[0], wordref : w[1]},
    success: function(resp){
        if(resp==="true"){
            y.textContent=resp;
            $('#err3').text("word updated");
        }
        else{
            $('#err3').text(resp);
        }

    },
    error: function(){
        $('#err3').text("Epic Fail");
    }
});
```

The aj_del_edit_word.php has this code only (for debugging purposes)

```
    print_r($_POST);
exit();
```

and the output is :

```
Array ( )
```

Am I doing something wrong or I'm missing something?

Comment: tyep:"Post", should be `type`

Comment: `tyep:"Post",` literal mistake

Comment: God, i check the spelling 10 times and never saw this one. and I spend an hour on this. Damn I need spellchecker.Thanks guys.

Comment: Because everyone looks firstly are errors that are more difficult. No one expects such simple errors :P I've spent some time to search such errors as well. That is why it's better when someone other looks at the script.

Answer (score 2):

You have literal mistake in your typo

```
$.ajax({
url:'../controllers/aj_del_edit_word.php',
tyep:"Post",'
```

should be changed to

```
$.ajax({
 url:'../controllers/aj_del_edit_word.php',
 type:"POST",
```